# M325 logitech mouse is not working with new batteries

Tags: laptop, mouse, battery

I have had this mouse for about a year now and it died yesterday when i was playing a game, so i wen't to find a new battery but none of them worked and i even checked that they were the right type. The thing is that when i put a battery in my mouse it will turn green for 10 seconds and turn off again. I saw from someone else's post thay they should press the reset button butvi couldent find one on mine. Do i need a new mouse or can i fix this?

Comment: But ur m325 is wireless and mini-usb! Try change other usb maybe conflict, or reinstall driver .. look a web http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-mouse-m325

Answer (score 1):

This will get better responses in [Logitech Forums](http://forums.logitech.com/). However, try doing the following.

- Run the Unifying software.
- Go to advanced.
- Click the entry for the Logitech M325 Mouse then click remove.
- Click the entry of the Unifying receiver then click pair a new device.
- Follow the on screen procedure to pair the Logitech M325 Mouse again.